# How to know which build tool is Intellij using?

Tags: java, build, intellij-idea

Sorry if this a noob question. I haven't understand much about these Java build tools.

As far as I know, in order to build a Java project automatically, a build tool must be used. Projects using Maven have `pom.xml`, those using Gradle have `build.gradle`. I have created a small Android project in Intellij and can build and run it normally. However, I don't find any such files. Does it mean that my project is not using Maven and Gradle? If so, what build tool is Intellij using to build my project?

Comment: I imagine it's managing the build itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (if not all) IDEs can build project themselves without any third party tool. Most IDEs however have either built-in or plugin-based integration with various build tools.

The reason is that IDE typically tries to simplify the developers's work. It builds project incrementally, uses various caches etc. Build tool however is designed mostly for batch execution. It also has incremental mode, but it is not optimized for "real-time" work.

Shortly, IntelliJ as other IDE can build project using its own mechanism. I however has integration with popular build tools like maven and gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Android Studio for Android Projects, which is powered by IntelliJ. Android Studio uses Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably using Apache Ant. Look for a build.xml file to confirm.